# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json"

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to use the JSON taglib to my JSP page but i am getting this error

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json"
```

I have added the tag lib,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
```

I am using environment `Java 1.8`

please give me any suggestion if i can parse JSON data in JSP in any other way.

I have added the screenshot please see below,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what is the problem.It's missing the JSON-taglib dependency.

You need to add the below dependency,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/atg.taglib.json/json-taglib -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>atg.taglib.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you get an error like missing artifact just download the jar and pom file from below link and put to your c:\users\.m2 folder

[JSON-taglib files](http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/atg/taglib/json/json-taglib/0.4.1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this:-

```
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %> 
 and 
<%@page import="com.google.gson.JsonObject"%>
```

OR

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
import="org.json.JSONObject,org.json.JSONException,java.util.*"%>
```

at the top of your Jsp page.

Comment: In which path in your jsp page.Is it in  **WEB-INF/lib**??

Comment: **Web-INF/View** jsp page

Comment: Make a Folder as  **WEB-INF/View**. then try. One more question do you add jstl tag library???

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer.I have followed your step still getting the same error.For your jstl question "Yes i have already used another taglib in my project"

Comment: please see my edited question i have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Remove this  <%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>  library. Becouse you have already import 
org.json.JSONObject,org.json.JSONException,java.util.* . Then see  you are getting your desired output or not. If this is not working then really I am sorry about it. Thank you for your response.